# get the data out of a database where date is today

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to get the data out of a database where date is today/one day.

```
$result16 = $dbhandle->query("SELECT DATE_SUB(signoff,INTERVAL 1 DAY)");
echo $result16;
$row_cnt16 = $result16->num_rows;
printf("Result set has %d rows.\n", $row_cnt16);
```

Im getting this error in the printf line:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in

The output of the echo is bool(false) anyone knows whats wrong?

Table information:
singoff is datatype timestamp and it saves the date someone signed off.

Comment: the output of it is bool(false) but i expected the list with signoff dates. Final result should be a number (rows counted) so i can put it into a chart.

Comment: I think your query is broken, check for any errors there first (what is signoff? what table are you using?)

Answer (score 0):

Below code will provide current date records:

```
$dbhandle->query("SELECT * FORM table_name WHERE signoff = DATE(NOW())");
```